# OpenGL shader linking error with no error message

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I've been trying to figure this one out for a long time, but can't manage to get things to work. I want simply to compile/run my OpenGL program, but my shaders does not link correctly and I get no helpful error message. In one case the error is purely empty, and in the other case it is `??y?` for some reason.

To create my program and compile my shaders, I have the following code:

```
GLuint buildProgram(const char* vertexShaderFile, const char* fragmentShaderFile)
{
    std::string vs = fileContents(vertexShaderFile);
    std::string fs = fileContents(fragmentShaderFile);
    return createProgram(vs.c_str(), fs.c_str());
}
```

The shaders look like

```
#version 330
out vec4 out_color; 
void main()
{
    out_color = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
}

#version 330
in vec4 in_Position;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = in_Position;
}
```

With

```
GLuint createProgram(const char* vertexSource, const char* fragmentSource)
{
    GLuint vertexshader = createShader(vertexSource, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentshader = createShader(fragmentSource, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint program = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(program, vertexshader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentshader);

    glLinkProgram(program);
    GLint ret;
    checkShader(vertexshader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &ret, "unable to link vertex shader");
    checkShader(fragmentshader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &ret, "unable to link fragment shader");

    glUseProgram(program);
    return program;
}

GLuint createShader(const char* source, GLenum shaderType)
{
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(shaderType);
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shader);
    GLint isCompiled = 0;
    checkShader(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isCompiled, "shader failed to compile");
    if (isCompiled == GL_FALSE)
    {
        glDeleteShader(shader);
        return 0;
    }
    return shader;
}
```

I try to generate error messages from the shaders by

```
void checkShader(GLuint shader, GLuint type, GLint* ret, const char* onfail)
{
    switch(type) {
        case(GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
        glGetShaderiv(shader, type, ret);
        if(*ret == false) {
            int infologLength = 0;
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);
            GLchar buffer[infologLength];
            GLsizei charsWritten = 0;
            std::cout << onfail << std::endl;
            glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, infologLength, &charsWritten, buffer);
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    case(GL_LINK_STATUS):
        glGetProgramiv(shader, type, ret);
        if(*ret == false) {
            int infologLength =  0;
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infologLength);
            GLchar buffer[infologLength];
            GLsizei charsWritten = 0;
            std::cout << onfail << std::endl;
            glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, infologLength, &charsWritten, buffer);
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    };
}
```

Running `GLuint program = buildProgram("shaders/test.vert", "shaders/test.frag");` gives me the following output:

> unable to link vertex shader
>
> unable to link fragment shader
>
> ??y?
>
> error build program
>      error 502 : GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Does anyone have a guess why my shaders compile just fine but does not link?

Comment: A shader object doesn't have a link state. Query the shader program object instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `getProgramiv(...,GL_LINK_STATUS,...)` on *shader* *objects*. It doesn't make the slightest sense to even call that `checkShader` function twice - once for each shader  object - when you try to get information about the *program* (of which there is only one). And it also doesn't make sense to name the function that way, for the `GL_LINK_STATUS` case.

Comment: Seems like I got stuff mixed up. Thanks for clearing that out!